# Yarn resolves to newer version instead of exact version

Tags: package.json, yarn-lock.json

If I understand the semver versioning correctly, this happens when upgrading a version.

Assuming version 1.5.0 is available.
Changing version to "^1.3.5" will resolve to "1.5.0"
Changing version to "~1.3.5" will resolve to latest in "1.3.x" range
Changing version to "1.3.5" will resolve to "1.3.5".

What could be the cause that my lock file shows multiple entries for the package? One for the 1.3.5 version and one for the latest version.